# computer science as a community service

Tags: computer-science

I came across [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/) today and that got me thinking about various community service software projects. What other community service software projects are there, whether they be web-based (as Ushahidi is) or not?

Note, I'm not talking about open source by itself, per se—although I presume most community service software will be opensource, I'm really aiming for more "help the disadvantaged of the world" type projects.

Anyone?

## List

- [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/) (PHP, MySQL)
- [One Laptop Per Child (software side of things)](http://laptop.org/) (Python and more)
- [Sahana](http://www.sahanafoundation.org/) (PHP, MySQL)

Comment: Just an idea, maybe we could list the languages used in each project?

Answer (score 1):

The FSF gives an Award for Projects of Social Benefit.  Not all of the projects are necessarily software projects, but some are.  They've awarded Wikipedia, Sahana, Groklaw, Creative Commons, and Internet Archive.

Probably [Sahana](http://sahanafoundation.org/) is the closest so far to what you're looking for.  It's a system to coordinate disaster relief.  It was originally developed for the 2004 Sri Lanka tsunami.

Answer (score 0):

Community service projects offer people an opportunity to give something back to their communities. Through community service, groups and individuals can take part in projects.

Apache Software Foundation (1991) is also a community service project.
Also,
JBoss(Java) is a community software.
And both these are open source software projects.